# Converting XML From Web Service to JSON & Mapping to an object - Angular

Tags: json, xml, angular, mapping, http-get

edit: solved

In the process of creating a project using angular. 
I have a service which is trying to display a list of objects. It uses a http.get and tries to map the response to json then to an object of Project(Which has properties project ID, name etc.) The problem is that the web service the data is from (on dev-teamcity) is in XML Format.

The web service looks like this: 
[image: Data I am trying to use]

When I run my app, no data at all is returned. 
How do I go about mapping this XML data to my Project object? 
I'm new to both angular and JS/TS and would appreciate any bit of help with this. Thanks in advance.
My Code:

project.model.ts:

```
export class Project {
    project_id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.project_id = obj.project_id;
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.description = obj.description;
    }
}
```

project.service.ts:

```
export abstract class ProjectService {
    //methods
    abstract fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]>;

}
```

project.service.http.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectServiceHttp extends ProjectService {

    //variables
    baseUrl = "...";

    //constructor
   constructor(private http: Http) {
        super();
    }

    //methods
    fetchProjects(): Observable<any>{
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
          .map((response: Response) => 
          {
            return response.json();
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
        }

        private handleError(error: any) {
            // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
            // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
            let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.log(errMsg); // log to console instead
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }

    GetProjectStatus(project_id: string): string {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    GetProjects(project_id: string): Project[] {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }


}
```

project.viewer.component.html:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'project-viewer',
      templateUrl: './project-viewer.html',  
    styleUrls: ['./project-viewer.css']
})

export class ProjectViewerComponent  {
    name = 'ProjectViewerComponent';
    projects: Project[];
    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;

    constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.fetchProjects();
    }

    private fetchProjects() {
        this.service
            .fetchProjects()
            .subscribe(response =>{
              this.projects = response;
              console.log(response);
            },
            errors=>{
               console.log(errors);
            });
    }

    private raiseError(text: string): void {
        this.stateValid = false;
        this.errorMessage = text;
    }
}
```

project-viewer.html:

```
<h3>Projects </h3>
<div >
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let project of projects" class="col-1-4">
            <li class ="module project" >
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{project.project_id}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
fetchProjects(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl, options)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

and in your component you could do this

```
private fetchProjects() {
        this.service
            .fetchProjects()
            .subscribe(response =>{
              this.projects = response;
            },
            errors=>{
               console.log(errors);
            }
    });
```

`this.project = response` will only work if in response, you api/backend is sending the exact replica of this.project, you may have to use reponse.data or response.result depending upon the data format that your api returns. You can console.log(response) and view the format of response.

Edit: You can call http.get(this.baseurl) if you don't want to use options and call it like this.

```
return this.http.get(this.baseurl)
          .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: The errors I get : 

"[ts] Cannot find name 'options'. Did you mean 'Option'?" - In the project.service.http.ts fetch projects method 

and
[ts]
Argument of type '(response: Response) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Promise<any>'.
  Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
and
[ts] Property 'handleError' does not exist on type 'ProjectServiceHttp'.

Comment: I now get a console error : ProjectViewerComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: something to do with my html file where I attempt to display the array of projects?

Comment: so in my fetchProjects method in my service, how do I map it to an array? like my original post the data is attempting to be mapped toa  jsonArray?

Comment: declare this.product and array like this product : Product[]  then use this.product.push(response);

Comment: I already do the line: this.projects = response in the fetchProjects method in the component?